# MongoDB - random and unique results

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection (let's call it `myColl`) with around 1000 documents like following:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e94b03a8397f71c25d95abb"), 
   "name" : "NameExample" 
}
```

I want to get 10 random and unique documents from `myColl`, and actually I'm doing it in this way:

```
db.myColl.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 10 } } ]
)
```

But today I read in the documentation that `$sample` may output the same document more than once in its result set. Does it mean that in my case I can get the same document twice (or even more)? If yes, what is the most efficient way to get random and unique results?

Comment: you use `.limit()` ?

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya no, why?